# jquery accordions in iframe not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

I have web-form with jquery accordions. You can check it here: http://www.citavicius.lt/egas/forma/indexas.php and firefox it showing normally.

But when i put it to iframe (for example: http://www.egas.lt/duju-iranga-automobiliams/) it looks bad (without any styles). This problem exists only when i'm trying it with firefox. Chrome, IE - showing everything ok.

Maybe some of you know, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reinitialize your scripts and stylesheets on your iframe too?

Comment: Yes. I'm reinitializing scripts and stylesheets.